# как увеличить время между выбором и отправкой запроса в базу из селекта с мультивыбором (GridView, yii2, kartik)?

Tags: yii2, gridview

Есть Gridview с товарами, есть поле в нём с характеристиками товаров. Есть желание с помощью селектора с мультивыбором выбирать товары с нужными характеристиками. Вот код фильтра

```
'filter' => \kartik\select2\Select2::widget([
        'name' => 'section_id',
        'data' =>         [
                'цвет' => [
                    '0' => 'синий', 
                    '1' => 'красный', 
                    '2' => 'зелёный', 
                ],
                'размер' => [
                    '11' => 'большой',
                    '22' => 'маленький',
                ]
        ],
        'value' => $searchModel->productParamsString,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'placeholder' => 'Выберите значение',
            'multiple' => true,
        ],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
            'selectOnClose' => true,
        ]
    ]),
```

Штука в том, что после каждого выбранного параметра отправляется запрос в базу и пока не обновилась страница ты можешь быстренько выбрать второй, третий параметр и так себе навыбирать. Но если ты стратил и не успел выбрать, то всё по-новой:)

У меня вопрос: можно ли увеличить время между выбором параметра и отправкой запроса в базу или вообще отменить автоматическую отправку запроса из этого поля и добавить кнопку "Отсправить"?

Comment: Может быть надо блокировать селект до того момента, пока не придет ответ от сервера?

Comment: Ну да, только как его сделать таким, чтоб на него не распространялось действие pjax’а в момент клика по первому <option>